# Wordpress REST API, GET featured image con una llamada

Tags: android, json, wordpress, webservice, rest

estoy realizando una aplicación en android para mi página wordpress. Quiero obtener varios datos del JSON, uno de ellos la imagen asociada a los posts. El JSON que devuelve wordpress por defecto tiene el siguiente formato:

```
"author": 5,
"featured_media": 1836,
"comment_status": "open",
"ping_status": "open",
"sticky": false,
"format": "standard",
"meta":
```

Con este formato el GET solo me devuelve el ID del archivo por lo que necesito hacer otra llamada al servicio para obtener la url de la imagen asociada al post. ¿Como podría obtener la url de la imagen directamente cuando me devuelve un post de la página? Ahora mismo estoy haciendo dos llamadas y es muy ineficiente y lento. He probado a realizar cambios en el plugin pero no cambia el formato. Alguna solución? Solo necesito que me devuelva la url de la imagen al hacer un GET de los posts de la página.

```
public class FeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<JSONArray>>{

private OnFeedListener listener;

public FeedTask(OnFeedListener listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<JSONArray> doInBackground(String... params) {
    ArrayList<JSONArray> arrays=new ArrayList<>();
    String url=params[0];
    OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
    Request.Builder builder=new Request.Builder();
    Request request=builder.url(url).build();
    try {
        Response response=client.newCall(request).execute();
        String json=response.body().string();
       try{
           JSONArray array= new JSONArray(json);
           //Array de Imágenes
           JSONArray arrayImages=new JSONArray();
           for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
               String urlImage=("http://MIPAGINA/wp-json/wp/v2/media/")+array.optJSONObject(i).optString("featured_media");
               request=builder.url(urlImage).build();
               response=client.newCall(request).execute();
               json=response.body().string();
               arrayImages.put(new JSONObject(json));
           }
           arrays.add(array);
           arrays.add(arrayImages);
           return arrays;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<JSONArray> array) {
    super.onPostExecute(array);
    if(array==null){
        return;
    }
    if(listener!=null){
        listener.onFeed(array);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: averiguaste si la API de wordpress te permite en una funcion devolver la imagen?

Comment: Creo que en esta versión no está disponible. Solo hay un archivo PHP que aparece como activado (plugin.php) y lo único relacionado con la imagen es esto:                                                                                   if ( isset( $wp_post_types['attachment'] ) ) {
  $wp_post_types['attachment']->show_in_rest = true;
  $wp_post_types['attachment']->rest_base = 'media';
  $wp_post_types['attachment']->rest_controller_class = 'WP_REST_Attachments_Controller';
 }

Comment: Y si busco el código del controlador en dicho archivo solo encuentro esto:     if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_REST_Attachments_Controller' ) ) {
 require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-attachments-controller.php';
}

Answer (score 0):

Pega esto en tu functions.php

```
//Prepare REST
function prepare_rest($data, $post, $request){
  $_data = $data->data;
  //Thumbnails
  $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
  //Acá puedes reemplazar el 'full' por el tamaño del thumbnail que hayas creado
  $thumbnailNews = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' );

  $_data['featured_news_image'] = $thumbnailNews[0];

  return $data;
}
add_filter('rest_prepare_post', 'prepare_rest', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Hola @user2996529. Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte. Creo que tu respuesta se podría beneficiar con una descripción más detallada acerca de qué trata tu propuesta de solución. Pensemos en todos los que puedan leer esta respuesta. ¿De qué se trata? ¿Cómo es que este código soluciones el problema? ¿Por qué sería la mejor forma de hacerlo? ¿Qué pasos se están siguiendo? Que la solución del código esté en la respuesta es genial, pero intentemos brindar la mayor calidad de contenido posible. Más info en [answer].